# Warning: Undefined array key, teniendo la key en el array PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli

intento consultar la información de un usuario mediante un query mysql y todo bien ahí. El problema es que al intentar imprimir algo de ese array asociativo me sale el error Warning: Undefined array key, teniendo esos datos en la variable. Aquí el código:

```
require_once 'connect_db.php';

session_start();

class Main extends Conexion
{

    protected $usuario;
    protected $ip_usuario;



    public function __construct()
    {

        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function validarSesion($usuario, $ip_usuario)
    {

        $this->usuario = $usuario;
        $this->ip_usuario = $ip_usuario;

       
        if (!isset($this->usuario) || !isset($this->ip_usuario) && ($this->ip_usuario != 
        $_SESSION['ip'] || empty($this->ip_usuario))) {

            return false;
        } else {

            return true;
        }
    }

    public function getUsuario()
    {

        if ($this->validarSesion($this->usuario, $this->ip_usuario) == true) {

            $query = "SELECT usuario,correo,nombres,apellidos,fecha 
            FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$this->usuario'";

            $consulta = $this->conexion->query($query); 

            $array = $consulta->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);   

            return $array; 

            

        }

        else {

            $error = 'Usuario no encontrado';
            return $error;

        }
    }
}

$usuario = new Main();

$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$ip_user = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$usuario->validarSesion($user, $ip_user);
$datos = $usuario->getUsuario();

echo $datos['correo'];

var_dump($datos);
```

En la salida obtengo lo siguiente:

Como pueden observar, en el array si tengo la key "correo", pero por alguna extraña razón que desconozco no me funciona.

Las soluciones que he intentado son las siguientes:

1. Añadir un alias a la consulta con 'AS'
2. Recorrer el array con un foreach
3. Comprobar si la función getUsuario(); retorna el array correctamente (Cosa que sí hace)

Error: Warning: Undefined array key "correo" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login POO\app\main.php on line 72

````
array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { ["usuario"]=> string(6) "admin3" ["correo"]=> string(13) "idk@gmail.com" ["nombres"]=> string(2) "Aa" ["apellidos"]=> string(2) "Bb" ["fecha"]=> string(10) "2021-10-11" } } ```
````

Comment: Si esta consulta está destinada a devolverte una sola fila, no tiene sentido usar `fetch_all` aquí, con `fetch_` simple bastaría, por ejemplo: `$array = $consulta->fetch_assoc();` Y, en el caso de que la consulta devolviese varias filas, sí podrías usar `fetch_all`, teniendo en cuenta que este método no es recomendable si se espera una gran cantidad de filas, pues podrías tener problemas de memoria, en cuyo caso es mejor obtener los datos aplicando `fetch_assoc` u otro de los métodos `fetch_` dentro de un bucle `while`.

Comment: @A.Cedano Muchas gracias:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El tema es que como observas el uso de: `fetch_all` te esta retornando un array que a su vez contiene otro donde se encuentran los datos recuperados de tu consulta.

Algo así:

```
[
   //este array esta en el índice 0
   [
       aquí los datos de la consulta
   ]
]
```

Entonces para acceder al email deberías pasar de esto:

```
echo $datos['correo'];
```

A esto otro donde indicas el índice 0

```
echo $datos[0]['correo'];
```

Sin embargo parece que buscas obtener los datos de un solo usuario, de ser así recomendaría cambiar [`fetch_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) por [`fetch_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) y pasarle como argumento la constante [`MYSQLI_ASSOC`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) de modo que la salida sea un array asociativo donde podrás ahora si emplear la sintaxis que tienes inicialmente en tu pregunta.

Quedando así:

```
.....
.....
$array = $consulta->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias bro, no tenía en cuenta el funcionamiento de fetch_all y fetch_array. Todo claro ahora.